# Can I connect to a remote desktop computer to make a call using a home telephone landline number?

Tags: networking, audio, vpn, remote-desktop, microphone

I am living in country B, I own a residence in country A where my family lives. There is a desktop computer that I remotely access and use through TeamViewer. Can I use that computer to make calls using country A’s home landline telephone number?

I was thinking maybe an external USB 56k modem [like this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005WQE25G) plus a piece of software would allow me to do it? Keep in mind I need to transfer my microphone input remotely. I think TeamViewer allows me to listen to the remote desktop computer, but I’m not sure it has the ability to share a host’s input device such as a microphone.

I’m using TeamViewer just to access some sites as if I were in country A, Can I setup a more elegant solution using openvpn or similar software/hardware? The inconveniences of my method—obviously—are that my desktop computer has to be powered on and accessible with TeamViewer running  on it, etc…

Any ideas? If you need more information, let me know.

Comment: My limited research shows that windows's built-in "[Phone Dialer](http://kb.swiftpage.com/rnt/rnw/img/enduser/18371_05.gif)" might just do the trick. You can easily access it by typing Dialer on the 'Run...' window (windows key + R). Btw, thanks for the edit.